# Python BeautifulSoup unable to join base URL and scraped truncated links,

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to webscrape player data with requests and BeautifulSoup adapting code from FCPython. I successfully grab and follow the teamlinks then get a truncated href for each player link but when i try to join the sites base url to the player link href i get issues. 
I cannot figure out why the base URL is often repeated multiple times before being joined to the truncated player link.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

- see code and output example below.

  ```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  from os.path  import basename

  headers = {'User-Agent': 
             'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

  page = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1'
  tree = requests.get(page, headers = headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(tree.content, 'html.parser')

  teamLinks = []

  links = soup.select("td.hauptlink.no-border-links.show-for-small.show-for-pad a")

  for i in range(0,20):
      teamLinks.append(links[i].get("href"))

  for i in range(len(teamLinks)):
      teamLinks[i] = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk"+teamLinks[i]

  playerLinks = []

  #Run the scraper through each of our 20 team links
  for i in range(len(teamLinks)):

      page = teamLinks[i]
      tree = requests.get(page, headers = headers)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(tree.content, 'html.parser')

      links = soup.select("span.show-for-small a")

      for j in range(len(links)):
          playerLinks.append(links[j].get("href"))

      for j in range(len(playerLinks)):
          playerLinks[j] = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk"+playerLinks[j]

      playerLinks = list(set(playerLinks))

  print(playerLinks)
  ```

  example output :-

  ```
  ['https://www.transfermarkt.co.ukhttps://www.transfermarkt.co.ukhttps://www.transfermarkt.co.ukhttps://www.transfermarkt.co.ukhttps://www.transfermarkt.co.ukhttps://www.transfermarkt.co.ukhttps://www.transfermarkt.co.ukhttps://www.transfermarkt.co.ukhttps://www.transfermarkt.co.ukhttps://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/ryan-fraser/profil/spieler/146795',
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
for j in range(len(playerLinks)):
    playerLinks[j] = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk"+playerLinks[j]
```

You are appending `"https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk"` again and again to strings found in list. Remove this loop and append the base url only once here:

```
playerLinks.append("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk" + links[j].get("href"))
```

The final code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os.path  import basename

headers = {'User-Agent':
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1'
tree = requests.get(page, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(tree.content, 'html.parser')

teamLinks = []

links = soup.select("td.hauptlink.no-border-links.show-for-small.show-for-pad a")

for i in range(0,20):
    teamLinks.append(links[i].get("href"))

for i in range(len(teamLinks)):
    teamLinks[i] = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk"+teamLinks[i]

playerLinks = []

#Run the scraper through each of our 20 team links
for i in range(len(teamLinks)):

    page = teamLinks[i]
    tree = requests.get(page, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(tree.content, 'html.parser')

    links = soup.select("span.show-for-small a")

    for j in range(len(links)):
        playerLinks.append("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk" + links[j].get("href"))

    playerLinks = list(set(playerLinks))

print(playerLinks)
```

Prints:

```
['https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/joshua-king/profil/spieler/91059', 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/michael-verrips/profil/spieler/288259', 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/teemu-pukki/profil/spieler/46972', 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/sander-berge/profil/spieler/333014', 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/dwight-mcneil/profil/spieler/584769', 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/sam-byram/profil/spieler/236953', 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/carlos-sanchez/profil/spieler/51226',

...
```